# git accuses that whole file was changed

Tags: git, github

I have an Eclipse RCP app, and git is now acting very weird. Everytime we change some line in class or any file, git accuses that whole file was changed.
See this gist: https://gist.github.com/luizkowalski/5968143
The only thing that was really changed was this line: `Bundle-Version: 2.6.13` to `Bundle-Version: 2.6.14`.
This behavior started some days ago. We do not updated git on our machines. This diff was generated by GitHub

Comment: Is this causing problems?

Comment: Sometimes, a developer change only one method on a class, and another dev change another method, and this behavior makes impossible to compare the changes and do the merge

Comment: As it literally affects all lines of your file I suspect someone has been messing with the [line endings settings](https://help.github.com/articles/dealing-with-line-endings)

Comment: Check out and save copies of both versions of the file, and carefully compare them (using `diff`, a binary editor, or whatever tools you have available). `cmp` will treat both files as binary and tell you the byte offset of the first difference. I suspect either a change to line endings or tab characters being expanded to spaces, or spaces unexpanded to tabs. You can also try `git diff -w` and `git diff -b`; see `git diff --help` for details.

Comment: What OS are you using? If you're using Cygwin on Windows, are you use Cygwin git or "git bash"? What editor(s) are being used to edit the file?

Comment: I use Windows, and some developers uses Linux. We all use Eclipse

Comment: Guess it was the line ending...we issued `git config --global core.autocrlf true` on all Windows machines, and the diffs are OK now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not a new feature or a bug. This is a result of something you guys committed unknowingly. Remember, Git is tracking all changes to the binary data of your repo. Several types of changes could have caused this. Has anyone copied the whole text of this document from one editor to another, replacing the original with the copy (perhaps across different operating systems)? Has the character set your project is using changed lately? Other things can cause this type of change detection too, but what is important to understand is that this is not an error on Git's part.

Comment: I thought the same thing about charset and I've double checked the configuration on workspace across all machines. They're all the same (UTF-8). I'm pretty sure that nobody copied all the text from one editor to another. What else can be?

Comment: Its not just copying, but opening and saving from another editor can result is this. Check the `end-line` character. Different editors may use different CRLF.

Comment: @Sailesh Makes a good point, end of file markers could be the issue. Don't forget that when moving from windows to unix different line endings are assigned. That could be your issue also.