# git single line change result in whole file changed

Tags: git, github, version-control

I have a file which I edited to include one new line at the end of the file. Now git is seeing the file as changed when I do a git diff on the file. I initially had the idea that it was caused by copying the change from one file to the current as per this thread: [git accuses that whole file was changed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17576974/git-accuses-that-whole-file-was-changed). But the same thing happens also in the case where I add the line by manually typing it in the file. That causes the file to go out of sync since the change commit is not entirely correct. Any ideas on how to mitigate the issue?

Comment: Probably the same issue, something like your editor converting DOS file endings to UNIX ones (or the reverse). No way to tell without the actual, byte-for-byte accurate files before/after.

Comment: Thanks Mat, you are completely right. I am using net beans for my work. I added a plugin that show the file endings. It was clear to see that the file uses a different file ending before the saved changes and after the change. It is probably because I work on the same project on a windows pc and a Linux box.

Comment: possible duplicate of [git accuses that whole file was changed](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17576974/git-accuses-that-whole-file-was-changed)